# Getting issue with Aspose.Email while splitting the pst file.Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, aspose

Getting issue with Aspose.Email dll while splitting the pst file.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
using (PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.FromFile(@"C:\Path.pst"))
{        
    pst.SplitInto(5000000, @"C:\Path2");
}
```

Is there any other way besides using  the Aspose.Email dll.

Comment: I am trying to split the file which is of 12gb.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your inquiry in [Aspose.Email forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) along with your sample PST file for further assistance. We'll look into it and assist you further accordingly.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.